# basic configuration of Jekyll minima theme

Tags: css, sass, jekyll-theme

I'm having some difficulties beginning configuration of `minima` theme for `Jekyll`. The theme is Jekyll's default, appears to be extremely popular, and the instructions in the [README](https://github.com/jekyll/minima) appear straightforward, though I can't get them to work. I might be doing something obviously wrong that someone here can see.

Here are the (annonymised) active lines from my `_config.yml`:

```yaml
title: IT thoughts...
author:
  name: joharr
  email: <myemailaddress>
description:
  Self-taught geekology...
baseurl: ""
url: <me>.github.io
twitter_username: <mine>
github_username:  <mine>

minima:
  skin: dark  # having no effect

theme: minima
```

- no dark skin applied. So I made `assets/css/` in the root of my site and copied the theme's [assets/css/style.scss](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/assets/css/style.scss) there, then:

```bash
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
...
style.scss:1: Error: File to import not found or unreadable: minima/skins/classic. (SassC::SyntaxError)
    on line 1:1 of style.scss
>> @import
...
```

- what!? I have to start copying over chains of the theme's SASS to do the slightest tweak? No idea now how to follow the theme's instructions and feel like one of the million plus happy users...

Answer (score 6):

I've figured it out - the answer's here, [Massively confused on how to use this theme's dark mode #599](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/issues/599)

> Minima's dark skin is an unreleased feature. It is available only via this repository.
> For that, you may use the ''jekyll-remote-theme'' plugin.

- `theme: minima` -> [minima](https://rubygems.org/gems/minima), the occasionally updated `gem`
- `remote_theme: jekyll/minima` -> [minima](https://github.com/jekyll/minima), the up-to-date repository on GitHub